# How to show total for stacked chart in Kendo Chart API

Tags: kendo-chart

I want to show total for stacked chart in Kendo Chart API. I have tried something which you can follow here http://dojo.telerik.com/acAHA/7

Comment: Please present what you have tried, what are the desired results, what were the actual results, pointing out the differences, so that you could receive the best assistance.

Comment: You will get from above URL, What I have tried.I want to show summation of stacked bar at the top of each series